# Global variables in phpunit_Selenium2

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I have an array with names I use to generate random names in a form and I want to use it in more then one function.

```
class TestMyTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {
public function setUp()
{
$this->setHost('localhost');
$this->setPort(4444);
$this->setBrowser("firefox");
$this->setBrowserUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
    public $firstNameArray = array(
    "Howard",
    "Sheldon",
    "Leonard",
    "Rajesh"
    );

    public $lastNameArray = array(
    "Wolowitz",
    "Cooper",
    "Hofstadter",
    "Koothrappali"
    );


public function testCreateNewCustomer()
{

    $name = rand(0,count($firstNameArray));
    $this->byId('customer-name')->value($firstNameArray[$name].' '.$lastNameArray[$name]);
    $random_phone_nr = rand(1000000,9999999);   
    $this->byId('customer-phone')->value('070'.$random_phone_nr);
    $this->byId('customer-email')->value($firstNameArray[$name].'.'.$lastNameArray[$name].'@testcomp.com');
}
```

This gives me the error "Undefined variable: firstNameArray" on the row where I declare the $name variabel. I dont want to have to have to declare the same array in every function I want to use it. so how do I solve this?

Comment: why do you want to use this data via a class variable? I Think you should consider using a Dataprovider (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) or simply put this date inside your test-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a global variable, it's a class/instance variable:

```
$this->byId('customer-name')->value($this->firstNameArray[$name].' '.$this->lastNameArray[$name]);
$this->byId('customer-email')->value($this->firstNameArray[$name].'.'.$this->lastNameArray[$name].'@testcomp.com');
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed another reference:

```
$name = rand(0,count($this->firstNameArray)-1);
```

Comment: Well I still get an error but a different one "Cannot access empty property" on the same line.

Comment: Yes I know, of course I edited all the rows with $firstNameArray pressent  to $this->$firstNameArray.

Comment: Your rand() should be between 0 and count-1, not between 0 and count

Comment: Oh sorry, well If I used fixed numbers since I knwo how big the array is now I get the old warning, "Undefined variable"

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that u removed the variable defenition in fron of the array name, why is that btw? why does it work with $this->firstNameArray byt not with $this->$firstNameArray;?

Comment: `$this->$firstNameArray` would be treated as a variable variable: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php - see Example #1